# Need to replace first line with the input from user in shell script

Tags: shell, sed

I am a newbie in shell scripting. I am making a script where I need to replace certain values in the first line of a file with an input value from the user. How can I achieve this?

I have these two lines in my file named exclude:

```
Exclude = CLASS:itsc_usa7061vm1300-1399
Exclude = RECYCLER
```

Now I want replace the everything after `CLASS:*` with any value from the user.

I used below command but it yielded no result:

```
sed "1s/*/Exclude = CLASS:$1/" exclude
```

Comment: `*` isn't the pattern for matching everything. `*` reverts to being literal in that usage so it just matches a literal `*`. You meant `.*` to match everything.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command instead cause your selector is selecting everything,

```
sed "1s/CLASS:.*/CLASS:$1/" exclude
```

**Output:**

```
$ a="hello"

$ echo $a

hello

$ sed "1s/CLASS:.*/CLASS:$a/" sample

Exclude = CLASS:hello
Exclude = RECYCLER
```

Comment: @Azhar if it worked please accept it as an answer by clicking the tick sign exactly below the down arrow. :)